# Is it possible to make a timer run in the background app even if the app is not in main focus?

Tags: java, android, onresume

i want my timer to keep running in the back of the app itself and when the user will re-open the app, it will go directly to that activity with the timer still running

Comment: This can be done using the `Service` since it will still be alive even though you killed the app, but if you force close the application it will kill the application and service as well.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to implement a Local Service. The usage is documented here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html

Answer (score 0):

By using service class and bind the service so that you can in background until you end service